# Shifting sum index

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X be a random variable that is poisson distributed. I compute:

$$E(X(X-1)) = \sum_{?}^{\infty} k(k-1) \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}= \sum_{?}^{\infty}  \frac{\lambda^k}{(k-2)!} e^{-\lambda}$$

What is the index of the sum: It has to be $k=2$, because k have to be $\geq 0$

Comment: Doesn't matter, $1/n! = 0$ if $n < 0$ anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have answered your own question.

The first sum can be from $k \ge 0$ since that is by definition. However, the first two terms vanishes and hence we can start from $k \ge 2$.

\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1) \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}&= 0(-1) \frac{\lambda^0}{0!}e^{-\lambda}+ 1(1-1) \frac{\lambda^1}{1!}e^{-\lambda}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1) \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1) \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{\lambda^k}{(k-2)!}e^{-\lambda}\\\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much:)